# Filter operation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, reduce

I am looking for a way to do this in Python without much boiler plate code.

Assume I have a list:

```
[(a,4),(b,4),(a,5),(b,3)]
```

I am trying to find a function that will allow me to sort by the first tuple value, and merge the list values together like so:

```
[(a,[4,3]),(b,[4,5])]
```

I know I can do this the naive way but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: how did a 5 turn into a 3 in your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict(list)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [("a",4), ("b",4), ("a",5), ("b",3)]

result = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in lst:
    result[a].append(b)

print sorted(result.items())

# prints: [('a', [4, 5]), ('b', [4, 3])]
```

Before the sort the algorithm has `O(n)` complexity; the group by algorithm has `O(n * log(n))` and the set/list/dict comprehension has something greater than `O(n^2)`

Comment: `i[0]` and `i[1]`? Why not just unpack the tuple?

Comment: No it's not. `for key, value in lst:`

Comment: ah, the real reason is that it is 1:22 AM

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'a' is your initial list an 'b' is the expected result, the following code will work:

```
d = {}
for k, v in a:
    if k in d:
        d[k].append(v)
    else:
        d[k] = [v] 
b = d.items()
```

Comment: this is the naive solution I wrote

Comment: This is another option
[(key,[v2 for k2, v2 in a if k2 == key ]) for key in list(set(map(lambda x: x[0], a)))]

Answer (score 0):

Not so efficient, but enough (with set + list + dict comprehension):

```
>>> data = [("a",4), ("b",4), ("a",5), ("b",3)]
>>> {key: [v for k, v in data if k == key]
...  for key in {k for k, v in data}
... }.items()
[('a', [4, 5]), ('b', [4, 3])]
```

Comment: I am sure this is good but a nightmare to read, I want people at any level of python to read it.

Comment: This is nowhere good, but it is a way to do it without using any statements :D

Comment: It's really not efficient but I still think this is the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (again assuming 'a' is the initial list)

```
[(key,[v2 for k2, v2 in a if k2 == key ]) for key in list(set(map(lambda x: x[0], a)))]
```

Comment: The casting to `list` isn't needed, as the set is already an iterable.